# Magento2. Product getImage returns Thumbnail instead of base

Tags: magento-2.1, image, product-images

I have a custom block, which extends from `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\AbstractView`.
Within this block I would like to retrieve the base image.
I've tried in this way

```
$this->getImage($this->getProduct(), 'product_page_image_small');
```

but what I get is the thumbnail instead of the base image. Should I extend from some other class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your argument to 'product_page_main_image' it should give you main image.

```
$this->getImage($this->getProduct(), 'product_page_main_image');
```

Comment: good, it works! How can I get the image url without resizing?

Comment: To understand these sizes have a look at view.xml file which defines all of these image sizes. It should be located under your custom theme/etc if not then you can copy it from luma/etc (theme). 
To get the Image url from your block you can use something like:
$block->getUrl('pub/media/catalog').'product'.$_product->getImage();

Comment: Yes, I knew it. I was wondering what is the best way to get the original file URL.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your argument in your phtml file,

```
1. product_page_image_medium
2. product_page_main_image
```

Above both argument gives you main image of product and using above argument your image should display like,

```
<width>700</width>
<height>560</height>
```

e.g.

```
$this->getImage($this->getProduct(), 'product_page_image_medium');
```

or

```
$this->getImage($this->getProduct(), 'product_page_main_image');
```

When you had used `product_page_image_small` its return only **88x110** size image.

You can more check size dimension from `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/etc/view.xml` file for size dimension.